# Bearings Question involving cosine rule

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Ship A is 120 nautical miles from lighthouse L on a bearing of 072°T, while ship B is 180 nautical miles from L on a bearing of 136°T. Calculate the distance between the two ships to the nearest nautical mile.

I've stuck on this question for a while.I have tried using the cosine rule, where I construct a triangle in which the angle is 136°, side a is 120 nautical miles side b is 180 nautical miles. But I'm nowhere near the answer even after doing that. I get the answer 279 for the missing side after calculating

$\sqrt{180^2+120^2-2*180*120*\cos(136)}$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: to find the length of a side of the triangle by a cosine rule the following equation applies:
$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2*b*c*cos(A)$, where "a", "b" and "c" are the sides of your triangle and "A" is the angle opposite to your "a" side.
So in order to evaluate "a" you need to square root the right side of your equation.
Can you attach a figure showing your problem?

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: You need to take a $cos(136-72)$ in your equation

Comment: $\sqrt{180^2 +120^2 - 2*180*120*cos(64)}=166.92$

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a $cos(136-72)$ in your equation.
Do you get correct answer then?

Comment: No, The answer needs to be in nautical miles, The answer is 167 nautical miles, I just don't know how they got 167 though.

Comment: Check this:$\sqrt{180^2 +120^2 - 2*180*120*cos(64)}=166.92$
I think this is your solution

Comment: Yes, I think that's it, but how did you get 64 for cos(64)?

Comment: By the cosine rule (there are several cases though) you need to take an angle between known sides. In your case this angle is between LA and LB, so 136-72=64